# Spring Kafka error after upgrading spring boot to 2.6.6

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-kafka, project-reactor

I am facing runtime error after I have upgraded spring boot version from 2.4.0 to 2.6.6 (and spring cloud version 2021.0.2). My application consumes messages from a kafka topic and produces it to another kafka topic after some transformation. I am getting below error as soon as the message is consumed.

> ERROR  ERROR   -   -   -   -   applog.cls=org.springframework.core.log.LogAccessor,applog.mthd=error,applog.line=149,applog.msg=Stopping container due to an Error,exc.stack=java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: LIFTER\n\tat org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.reactor.ReactorHooksHelper.getLifterName(ReactorHooksHelper.java:171)\n\tat org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.reactor.ReactorHooksHelper.isTraceContextPropagator(ReactorHooksHelper.java:175)\n\tat org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.reactor.ReactorHooksHelper.shouldDecorate(ReactorHooksHelper.java:121)\n\tat reactor.core.publisher.Operators$LiftFunction.apply(Operators.java:2488)\n\tat reactor.core.publisher.Operators$LiftFunction.apply(Operators.java:2449)\n\tat reactor.core.publisher.Flux.onAssembly(Flux.java:9692)\n\tat reactor.core.publisher.Flux.fromIterable(Flux.java:1118)\n\tat com.org.listener.MyListener.listen(MyListener.java:32)\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)\n\tat sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\n\tat java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)\n\tat org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:169)\n\tat org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:119)\n\tat org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.HandlerAdapter.invoke(HandlerAdapter.java:56)\n\tat org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:339)\n\tat org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.BatchMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invoke(BatchMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:180)\n\tat org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.BatchMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(BatchMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:172)\n\tat org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.BatchMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(BatchMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:61)\n\tat org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeBatchOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2268)\n\tat org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeBatchOnMessageWithRecordsOrList(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2258)\n\tat org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeBatchOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2204)\n\tat org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeBatchListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2114)\n\tat org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeBatchListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1997)\n\tat org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1976)\n\tat org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeIfHaveRecords(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1364)\n\tat org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1355)\n\tat org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1247)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:266)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java)\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)\n

I tried checking the reactor-core ReactorHooksHelper.java file, but field LIFTER seems to be present there. Need help to understand why service is giving this error.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Gary Russell can you please help in this?

Comment: I cannot, no; looks like it has nothing to do with Spring; some kind of reactor jar incompatibility.

Comment: What steps can i take to figure out the solution on my own in this case @GaryRussell?

Comment: Aside from verifying you have the correct set of Reactor jars, I have no idea.

Comment: Thanks Gary, the reason was incompatible reactor jar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like issue with reactor. Which version of reactor-core are you having? For spring-boot version 2.6.6 try using reactor-core version `3.4.16`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
    <artifactId>reactor-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.16</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't specify a version for reactor-core. Spring-boot-dependencies takes care of that for you and would automatically use 3.4.16 of reactor-core. That's the beauty of using Spring Boot.

Check out this POM file

https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-dependencies/2.6.6/pom

and search for `<reactor-bom.version>` and notice that the version is `2020.0.17`.

After that, find the equivalent reactor-bom file

https://search.maven.org/artifact/io.projectreactor/reactor-bom/2020.0.17/pom

and notice that the version for reactor-core is 3.4.16

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
  <artifactId>reactor-core</artifactId>
  <version>3.4.16</version>
</dependency>
```